# Is there a way to convert the contents of a Java swing file into a GUI designer?

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I have just coded a GUI written with Java swing, and I was wondering if I can edit my GUI with a GUI designer. I do not have a .form file, so I do not know how to approach this problem.

I heard Intellij has a snapshot tool which converts GUI to there GUI designer, but I could not locate it.

Comment: Don't. Most designers produce unreadable and unmaintainable code. We don't support it here

Comment: What g00se said.  Don’t use a GUI designer.  Not only is the code dreadful and unmaintainable, it’s truly bad code.  You should never set hard-coded positions and sizes on components—that will lead to an application that looks broken on other computers with different fonts and different monitor sizes.